# Why do non-zero integers evaluate to True, but not equal True(n == True; n > 1)?

Tags: python

For instance, in an interactive Python 3.5 session,

```
>>> True if 5 else False
True
>>> True if 5 == True else False
False
```

Bonus question: why is 1 the exception?

```
>>> True if 1 == True else False
True
```

Comment: True coerces to 1.

Comment: `True` equals to `1` and `False ` equals to 0 in boolean logic.

Comment: @GeekSambhu in Python's implementation you mean. This is invalid in C#: `true == 5` gives a syntax error.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Thanks, booleans are actually integers in python